# how to remove 0's from a string without impacting other cells in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which has "0's" and looks as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'WARNING':['4402,43527,0,7628,54337',4402,0,0,'0,1234,56437,76252',0,3602],
    'FAILED':[0,0,'5555,6753,0','4572,0,8764,8753',9876,0,'0,4579,7514']
})
```

I want to remove the zeroes from the strings where there are multiple values such that the results df looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'WARNING':['4402,43527,7628,54337',4402,0,0,'1234,56437,76252',0,3602],
    'FAILED':[0,0,'5555,6753','4572,8764,8753',9876,0,'4579,7514']
})
```

However the ones which have individual 0's in a cell should remain intact. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'WARNING':['0,0786,1230,01234,0',4402,0,0,'0,1234,56437,76252',0,3602],
    'FAILED':[0,0,'5555,6753,0','4572,0,8764,8753',9876,0,'0,4579,7514']
})
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('0,|,0')).replace(",0,", ",")
```

Output:

```
            WARNING            FAILED
0    786,1230,01234               NaN
1               NaN               NaN
2               NaN         5555,6753
3               NaN  4572,0,8764,8753
4  1234,56437,76252               NaN
5               NaN               NaN
6               NaN         4579,7514
```

Comment: For example if the number is`'0,0xxx,xxx0,xxx'`

Comment: perfect Thanks so much @Chirag!

Comment: You should fix it

Comment: That is more like my old answer , strip will remove the 0 from `0,0xxx` both of them, still not correct then .

Comment: @W-B O, yes. Agree

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it with a list comprehension.

```
In [1]: df.apply(lambda col: col.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ','.join([y for y in x.split(',') if y != '0']) if ',' in x else x), axis=0)
Out[1]:  
           FAILED                WARNING
0               0  4402,43527,7628,54337
1               0                   4402
2       5555,6753                      0
3  4572,8764,8753                      0
4            9876       1234,56437,76252
5               0                      0
6       4579,7514                   3602
```

Breaking it down:

1. Iterate over all columns with `df.apply(lambda col: ..., axis=0)`
2. Convert each column's values to string with `col.astype(str)`
3. Apply a function to each "cell" of `col` with `.apply(lambda x: ...)`
4. The `lambda` function first checks if `','` exists in `x`, otherwise returns the original value of `x`
5. If `',' in x`, it splits `x` by `','`, which creates a list of `y`'s
6. It keeps only the `y != '0'`
7. It joins everything at the end with a `','.join(...)`

Comment: I assumed the values of the dataframe are lists that were joined into a string, so this seemed the most natural approach. Split the string into a list again, filter only the values you want and join everything back into a string at the end. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with a negative look behind to replace `0,` only if it not preceded by another digit.

```
import re

df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'(?<![0-9])0,', '', str(x)))

                 WARNING          FAILED
0  4402,43527,7628,54337               0
1                   4402               0
2                      0     5555,6753,0
3                      0  4572,8764,8753
4       1234,56437,76252            9876
5                      0               0
6                   3602       4579,7514
```

For the test case W-B points out:

```
s = '0,0999,9990,999'
re.sub(r'(?<![0-9])0,', '', s)
#'0999,9990,999'
```